# can girls study in co-education systems?

Tags: fiqh, children, education, school

Can girls study with boys in co-education systems?  as now every school or college is co-education and it is a necessity to have proper education so does it make us a bad Muslim?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Muslim country, then they have to create a separate school/college for girls, if not then YES we can go to any school/college because education is more important in Islam.

After Jung-e-Badar Prophet S.A.W. announced who ever will teach to 10 children he will freed out.

Quran revealed starting with "READ" (IQRA)

> Bukhari: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "He who has a slave-girl and educates and
>   treats her nicely and then manumits and marries her, will get a double
>   reward.

Comment: Here, "Education" refers to Islamic teachings. But, modern education (in schools and colleges) is not (or atleast not limited to) that.

Comment: @Ali Even in a muslim country, you can have separate classrooms but a co-ed school for the two genders. My school  had co-ed classes in primary and then separate rooms from middle school given that majority of the kids hit puberty around that time.

Comment: @Ahmed 5, you are lucky but the people are living in India/Pakistan/Bangladhes/China are not as lucky as you are.

Comment: The used evidence hardly applies for the topic of the question. Educates here is more about manners than about whatever one may learn in a school.